# Does a weapon with concentration spell enchantment require concentration from the user?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, spellcasting, concentration

Does a weapon that is enchanted with the ability to cast a spell that is a concentration spell, require concentration from the user to maintain?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yes, the user must maintain concentration. The DMG says this about items that cast spells (on page 141):

> The spell uses its normal casting time, range, and duration, and **the user of the item must concentrate if the spell requires concentration**.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but some items give spell like effects without requiring concentration.  See [Do magic item spells require concentration?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/99199/do-magic-item-spells-require-concentration/99202#)

Comment: Please quote the relevant information from the link in your answer here. While the link may answer the question, it's best to provide that information yourself in your own answer in case the link goes down and as such invalidates your answer.