# Does the Elemental Gem require Concentration?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, concentration

Does an elemental summoned from an Elemental Gem require Concentration? I am getting hung up on the "as if you had cast" part. Other items say, "you can use an action to cast the [spell]".

[Elemental Gem](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/elemental-gem)

> This gem contains a mote of elemental energy. When you use an action
> to break the gem, **an elemental is summoned as if you had cast the
> *conjure elemental* spell**, and the gem's magic is lost. The type of gem
> determines the elemental summoned by the spell.

---

Related question: [Do magic item spells require concentration?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/99199/do-magic-item-spells-require-concentration)

The distinction I'm asking then is if the Elemental Gem is a spell or a spell-like effect.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### It requires concentration.

You have noted the relevant text from the item description:

> an elemental is summoned *as if you had cast the conjure elemental spell*.

"As if you had cast" indicates that we treat you as if you had cast the *conjure elemental* spell. Which, if you had cast the *conjure elemental* spell, you would be concentrating on it, since it requires concentration.